# Replacing ASCII emotions with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently using jQuery on a Chrome extension to replace ASCII smilies with an image. I am using regular expressions. The problem is, it seems to crash pages like Facebook. Is there a quicker way to do what I'm trying to do to ensure pages don't crash?

```
function replaceEmotions() 
{
var emotions = {
    smile: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/10.gif') + '" />',
    wink: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/4.gif') + '" />',
    sad: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/23.gif') + '" />',
    angry: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/1.gif') + '" />',
    bigsmile: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/2.gif') + '" />',
    crying: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/13.gif') + '" />',
    surprised: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/23.gif') + '" />',
    tounge: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/14.gif') + '" />',
    cool: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/24.gif') + '" />',
    shh: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/7.gif') + '" />',
    confused: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/40.gif') + '" />',
    blushing: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/9.gif') + '" />',
    kiss: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/6.gif') + '" />',
    huh: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/32.gif') + '" />',
    heart: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/38.gif') + '" />',
    sick: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/29.gif') + '" />',
    sarcastic: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/3.gif') + '" />',
    laughing: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/16.gif') + '" />',
    cantWatch: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/15.gif') + '" />',
    omg: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/32.gif') + '" />',
    wtf: '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('images/18.gif') + '" />',
};

var patterns = {
    smile: /:\)/gm,
    wink: /;\)/gm,
    sad: /:\(/gm,
    angry: />:o/gm,
    bigsmile: /:\D/gm,
    crying: /:'\(/gm,
    surprised: /:o/gm,
    tounge: /:p/gm,
    cool: /B\)/gm,
    shh: /:x/gm,
    confused: /:s/gm,
    blushing: /:\$/gm,
    kiss: /:*/gm,
    huh: /:\//gm,
    heart: /\<3/gm,
    sick: /:\&/gm,
    sarcastic: /:\>/gm,
    laughing: /=D/gm,
    //cantWatch: /x_x/gm,
    //omg: /o_o/gm,
    //wtf: /o_O/gm,
}

// :) ;) :( >:o :D :'( :o :p B) :x :s :$ :* :/ <3 :& :> =D x_x o_o o_0

$('.messageBody, .commentBody').each(function() {
    var $content = $(this);
    var html = $content.html();

    $content.html(
        html.replace(patterns.smile, emotions.smile) . 
        replace(patterns.wink, emotions.wink) . 
        replace(patterns.sad, emotions.sad) . 
        replace(patterns.angry, emotions.angry) .
        replace(patterns.bigsmile, emotions.bigsmile) .  
        replace(patterns.crying, emotions.crying) . 
        replace(patterns.surprised, emotions.surprised) . 
        replace(patterns.tounge, emotions.tounge) . 
        replace(patterns.cool, emotions.cool) . 
        replace(patterns.shh, emotions.shh) . 
        replace(patterns.confused, emotions.confused) . 
        replace(patterns.blushing, emotions.blushing) . 
        replace(patterns.kiss, emotions.kiss) . 
        replace(patterns.huh, emotions.huh) . 
        replace(patterns.heart, emotions.heart) . 
        replace(patterns.sick, emotions.sick) . 
        replace(patterns.sarcastic, emotions.sarcastic) . 
        replace(patterns.laughing, emotions.laughing)
    );
});
```

Comment: While you're looking for a *quicker* way to do it, you should also be looking for a *correct* way.  Consider for example that your solution will try to stick an `<img>` tag in the middle of elements with those patterns in attribute values. `<span class='type:paragraph'>` for example.

Comment: There's only 2 places it will replace emotions and they don't have HTML syntax within the elements that contains the text. I did already check for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a callback function, so you will only need to call `replace` once.

```
function replaceEmotions(html) 
{
    var icons = {
        ':)':'images/00.gif',
        ';)':'images/01.gif',
        ':(':'images/02.gif',
        '>:o':'images/03.gif',
        ':D':'images/04.gif',
        ':\'(':'images/05.gif',
        ':o':'images/06.gif',
        ':p':'images/07.gif',
        'B)':'images/08.gif',
        ':x':'images/09.gif',
        ':s':'images/10.gif',
        ':$':'images/11.gif',
        ':*':'images/12.gif',
        ':/':'images/13.gif',
        '<3':'images/14.gif',
        ':&':'images/15.gif',
        ':>':'images/16.gif',
        '=D':'images/17.gif'
        }
    var search = '';
    for(var i in icons)
      search += i.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')+'|';//escape characters and add 'or'
    search = search.substr(0, search.length-1);//remove last 'or'

    var replaceCallback = function(match) {
      return '<img src="' + chrome.extension.getURL(icons[match]) + '" />'; 
    }

    return html.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gm'), replaceCallback);
}

$('.messageBody, .commentBody').each(function() {
    var $content = $(this);
    var html = $content.html();
    html = replaceEmotions(html)
    $content.html(html);
});
```

I re purposed the `replaceEmoticons` function to be more generic. I put the jQuery outside and make it call `replaceEmoticons` for every commentBody. This way `replaceEmoticons` can be reused someplace else more easily.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the refactoring. I'm not to sharp on Regular Expressions. The RegExp the code produces works, but it fails to match ':)'. Any ideas?

Comment: That's weird. I just tested it and it is replacing `:)` just fine. I used the test strings 'hello :) world' and even just ':)', both get replaced by the img code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps.

I see that you're using method chaining for replacing all the emotions.

This consumes lots of memory since the new html content should be stored in let say, interpreter's stack in each `replace()` call, for the next chain. That might be the reason it crashes `Chrome`.

Using something like this you can achieve the same result with fewer lines of code and also it's more efficient:

```
$html = $content.html();
$(patterns).each(function(key, value) {
    $html = $html.replace(value, emotions[key]);
});
$content.html($html);
```